# Import a third party Jar file to Beanshell sampler having error when running

Tags: jmeter, smack

Creating User Define Variable, with 3 variables CHAT_HOST, CHAT_PORT, CHAT_SERVICE
And assign value to them.

Putting 2 Smack 3.0 file to /lib folder of Jmeter and creating the Beanshell sampler with the code as below:

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;


ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration();
ConnectionConfiguration.init(vars.get("CHAT_HOST"), vars.get("CHAT_PORT"), vars.get("CHAT_SERVICE"));
XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
connection.connect();
```

But, when running the console shows error as below:

```
WARN  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BSFSampler: BSF error org.apache.bsf.BSFException: BeanShell script error: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration; import org.jivesoftware.s . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Undefined argument: HOST  : at Line: 7 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration; import org.jivesoftware.s . . . '' : ( HOST , PORT , SERVICE ) 
 BSF info: script at line: 0 column: columnNo
    at bsh.util.BeanShellBSFEngine.eval(BeanShellBSFEngine.java:199)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BSFSampler.sample(BSFSampler.java:104)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Would you like to tell me how to handle this error, and the way to call a class from third party Jar file as I did - is it right or wrong ? If wrong, please instruct me.

Thanks,

Comment: did you ensure that CHAT_HOST, CHAT_PORT, CHAT_SERVICE have the values as expected??

Comment: before passing value to ConnectionConfiguration.init() perform null check on three variables you are referring named CHAT_host,port&service.                                           `String chat_host= vars.get("chat_host");
if (chat_host== null) {chat_host="";}`

Comment: @vlns, Nithin CV: The value of char_host, port, service is defined on User Defined element.

Comment: @all: I edited my description a little for understand this issue easily.

Comment: @all: any suggestion ? please help me

Answer (score 0):

From error message, it seems that :

- vars.get("CHAT_HOST") contains HOST
- vars.get("CHAT_PORT") contains PORT
- vars.get("CHAT_SERVICE") contains SERVICE

So check the values in User Defined Variables.

Also I would advise moving from Beanshell to JSR223 using Groovy as error messages will be much clearer and performances much better.

It is the adivsed way of doing custom scripting in JMeter.